# How to implement Proximal Policy Optimization (PPO) Algorithm for classical control problems?

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement clipped PPO algorithm for classical control task like keeping room temperature, charge of battery, etc. within certain limits. So far I've seen the implementations in game environments only. My question is the game environments and classical control problems are different when it comes to the implementation of the clipped PPO algorithm? If they are, help and tips on how to implement the algorithm for my case are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering your question from a general RL point of view, I don't think the particular algorithm (PPO) makes any difference in this question.

I think there is no fundamental differences, both can be seen as discrete control problems. In a game you observe the state, then choose an action and act according to it, and receive reward an the observation of the subsequent state.

Now if you take a simple control problem, instead of a game you probably have a simulation (or just a very simple dynamic model) that describes the behavior of your problem. For example the equations of motion for an inverted pendulum (another classical control problem). In some case you might directly interact with the real system, not a model of it, but this is rare as it can be really slow, and the typical sample complexities of RL algorithms make learning on a real (physical) system less practical.

Essentially you interact with the model of your problem just the same way as you do with a game: you observe a state, take an action and act, and observe the next state. The only difference is that while in games reward is usually pre-defined (some score or goal state), probably you need to define the reward function for your problem. But again, in many cases you also need to define rewards for games, so this is not a major difference either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have couple of points that confused me. 1) When you start learning, you have no samples so I draw random actions uniformly, so in the initial fitting my old probability distribution is 1/n_actions, right? 2) When an episode ends and a new one starts, what is the old probability distribution, uniform?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your questions right, but I try to answer it. In general in deep RL you have a policy, which is represented by a neural network. For discrete actions you use a soft-max output layer, and this **is** your probability distribution over actions. You act in the environment by sampling from the actions according to your policy network's output probabilities.

1) At first you randomly initialize your network, so the initial distribution is most probably fairly close to uniform.

2) I don't think so.

Comment: I found two implementations of PPO in github, https://github.com/OctThe16th/PPO-Keras/blob/master/Main.py and https://github.com/liziniu/RL-PPO-Keras/blob/master/ppo.py. They both use dummy_value and dummy_action=np.zeros((1, NUM_ACTIONS)), np.zeros((1, 1)), respectively, to get action using trained model . Why would they use zero values for action prediction?

Comment: In the first linked implementation the policy network gets the previous policy output and  action value as inputs. At the first step this is just substituted with zeros (the dummy vectors). So it's only needed for the neural network (it needs the same number of inputs every time), but not a necessary part of the algorithm itself.

Comment: btw I think we are getting a bit further from your original question. Feel free to post another question, but if you value the answer I gave, please consider marking it as an accepted answer.